# How to exclude 4th-gen iPod touch for app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch

I want to release an app for the following devices

- iPad 2 or higher
- iPhone 4 or higher
- iPod 5 (or higher)

The problem is that I can't find something to exclude the 4th-gen iPod touch but it doesn’t have enough RAM to run the app, so it crashes every time. Does anyone has experience with that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can only exclude devices based on features, listed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

I am not aware of any feature that will eliminate an iPod touch 4th gen, I believe your only option is to optimise further.

Comment: look here http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix

Comment: Optimising further is not possible. The game grafics and stuff just take to much RAM at the late game so it will crash always. Excluding the iPhone 4 is no option as well (I mean srsly you can't exclude the most spreaded device :D)

Comment: Does the 5th gen iPod touch contain a magnetometer? Because the 4th gen iPod apparently does not have one, while more recent iOS devices tend to have them.